# Swift subprotocol with associated type

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, associated-types

I'd like to know how this type of relation (example in kotlin) would be expressed in Swift

```
interface Index<K, V> {
  fun getAll(key: K): Sequence<V>
}
```

I tried to use protocols with associated types, like this:

```
protocol Index {
    associatedtype Key
    associatedtype Value
    associatedtype Result: Sequence where Sequence.Element == Value

    func getAll(key: Key) -> Result
}
```

but this didn't work (`Associated type 'Element' can only be used with a concrete type or generic parameter base`)

Then, as a workaround, i tried this:

```
protocol Index {
    associatedtype Key
    associatedtype Value

    func get<T: Sequence>(key: Key) -> T where T.Element == Value
}
```

But this doesn't really seem like the right / idiomatic way to do it.

There are only two constraints:

1. Sequence can't be a concrete type
2. None of the methods on Index have a meaningful implementation

Notes:

- There will be a class / type that implements `Sequence` that is specific to each implementation of `Index`

I'm open to any other structural change!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use the associated type's name, not the inherited protocol's name:

```
associatedtype Result: Sequence where Result.Element == Value
//                                    ^^^^^^
```

Note that Swift's standard library now includes a type named `Result`, so you might want to use a different name for your `associatedtype`. I use `Answer` in my own code:

```
associatedtype Answer: Sequence where Answer.Element == Value
```

(In Smalltalk, return values are called “answers”.)

Comment: That's really interesting. And it makes sense, of course. It would be somewhat wise for the Swift team to make a guide for non objective-c developers as the syntax is pretty different from other languages.

Comment: Does this still work? I am getting "'A' is not a member type of 'Self.Result'".

Comment: Actually it never worked. My example involving `Either` had several flaws so I've removed it.