# Swift Associated type constraints

Tags: swift, associated-types

I have two protocols with each defining an associated type. One of the protocols needs to define a variable of typed the other protocol where they both have the same type for associated type. Is it possible to somehow infer the type of associated type?

```
protocol A {
    associatedtype AModel
    var b: B { get }
}

protocol B {
    associatedtype BModel
    func doAnother(anotherModel: BModel)
}
```

Here is what I tried with no success

```
protocol A {
    associatedtype AModel
    associatedtype TypedB = B where B.BModel == AModel
    var another: TypedB { get }
}

protocol B {
    associatedtype BModel
    func doAnother(anotherModel: BModel)
}
```

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_associated_type_chains

Comment: That works because `protocol Superfighter {}` one of the protocols doesn't have an associatedtype

Answer (score 1):

Please find the following working playground example. You need to use the associated type's name, not the constraining protocol's name. The reason for this is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48957528/5722895).

```
import Foundation

protocol A {
    associatedtype AModel
    associatedtype TypedB: B where TypedB.BModel == AModel
    var another: TypedB { get }
}

protocol B {
    associatedtype BModel
    func doAnother(anotherModel: BModel)
}

// compiles

struct One: B {
    typealias BModel = String
    func doAnother(anotherModel: String) {}
}

struct Second: A {
    typealias AModel = String
    typealias TypedB = One
    var another: One
}

// does not compile

struct Third: B {
    typealias BModel = Int
    func doAnother(anotherModel: Int) {}
}

struct Fourth: A { // A' requires the types 'Fourth.AModel' (aka 'String') and 'Third.BModel' (aka 'Int') be equivalent
    typealias AModel = String
    typealias TypedB = Third
    var another: Third
}
```

Comment: This was great until I had to create an implementation of A. It forces you to define TypedB with a concrete implementation :(

Comment: May you please precise your question then? I don’t get what you want to achieve.